# Removing emojibubbleshooter chrome notification

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I have emojibubbleshooter notification on chrome every once in while.
(https://emojibubbleshooter.com/?utm_source=notif_wct)

I haven't installed new extensions for few months so I am not sure why I am getting this ad.

I checked notification tab, and found the following :

[image]

What is this 'games alert'? I checked my application folder but I don't have an app named like that. I can set the notification to None but is there a way to remove this 'Games' completely from my mac?

Currently using Nod32 Internet security for mac and no virus apparently.

My list of installed extensions from chrome://system:

> aapocclcgogkmnckokdopfmhonfmgoek : Slides : version 0_10
>   ahfgeienlihckogmohjhadlkjgocpleb : Web Store : version 0_2
>   aiimdkdngfcipjohbjenkahhlhccpdbc : Flash Video Downloader : version 31_2_3
>   aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake : Docs : version 0_10
>   apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf : Google Drive : version 14_1
>   blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo : YouTube : version 4_2_8
>   cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm : uBlock Origin : version 1_14_24
>   dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo : Tampermonkey : version 4_5
>   eocfeihmkgnmldnhgijijlffdpegocnh : jBart Crawler : version 0_8_4
>   fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl : Full Page Screen Capture : version 2_2
>   felcaaldnbdncclmgdcncolpebgiejap : Sheets : version 1_2
>   fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop : Postman : version 5_5_1
>   gfdkimpbcpahaombhbimeihdjnejgicl : Feedback : version 1_0
>   ghbmnnjooekpmoecnnnilnnbdlolhkhi : Google Docs Offline : version 1_4
>   hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd : LastPass: Free Password Manager : version 4_5_0_5
>   ipkbbcamfcnlflkedfdaokofdmfgocfp : Mudfish - HTTP Proxy : version 4_4_5
>   jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik : Speed Dial 2 : version 2_2_0
>   jpkfjicglakibpenojifdiepckckakgk : Gestures for Google Chrome™ : version 1_13_4
>   kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen : Grammarly for Chrome : version 14_824_1430
>   kmendfapggjehodndflmmgagdbamhnfd : CryptoTokenExtension : version 0_9_46
>   mfehgcgbbipciphmccgaenjidiccnmng : Cloud Print : version 0_1
>   mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja : Google Dictionary (by Google) : version 4_0_8
>   mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai : Chrome PDF Viewer : version 1
>   nbokbjkabcmbfdlbddjidfmibcpneigj : SmoothScroll : version 1_6_1
>   neajdppkdcdipfabeoofebfddakdcjhd : Google Network Speech : version 1_0
>   nkeimhogjdpnpccoofpliimaahmaaome : Google Hangouts : version 1_3_5
>   nmmhkkegccagdldgiimedpiccmgmieda : Chrome Web Store Payments : version 1_0_0_3
>   ocpcmghnefmdhljkoiapafejjohldoga : Context Menu Search : version 2_93
>   ojplelelocihfchkdaebocpankipadmp : Scopus Document Download Manager : version 2_0_2
>   pfmgfdlgomnbgkofeojodiodmgpgmkac : Data Saver : version 2_0_2
>   pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia : Gmail : version 8_1
>   pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm : Chrome Media Router : version 6317_1002_0_5

What are these strings before ':' by the way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Game Center(or simply Games)

is an application that comes with any Apple-made device(no need to delete it).

## "Games alert"

should be broken up into "*games* | alert style"

## Strings before :

not really a part of this question but: Seems to be some kind of ID string.

## Removing the ad

has nothing to do with Games, you have to do it in Chrome settings(somewhere with "notifications" or similar)

Comment: Thank you so much, it was indeed in the notification tab hidden in the chrome setting page! Have a nice day.